# Using a hardware load balancer for PostgreSQL / MySQL

Tags: database, cluster, load-balancing

I need to ensure high availability of my 3-tier architecture system. Currently I have the database mirrored by using MySQL Master-Master. All app boxes talk to the primary DB server

In case of primary DB hardware failure then the application needs to be switched to the secondary .. and that is manual. I want to make this automatic, using heartbeat and IP takeover etc., is possible but that has too many problems.

How is this problem solved normally. Is it a good idea to use a load balancer like F5 to route all DB traffic and then switch in case of failure